# In-App purchase: download all hosted content by Full purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I am developing app in which user can download some file from In-app purchase. I can download in-app purchase for single item. 
Now I want to add one "Complete set" in-app purchase item. By purchasing it, user can download all in-app purchase items.

Please suggest how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you must have to provide two separate files or zip (one for sample and another for full download) you can provide sample file as free and full content paid

simply manage your content with unique id like

sample + id + extension

full + id + extension

sample004.zip
full004.zip

Comment: Actually,there are three files which I can download it by indiviual purchase, or by download Only one item (complete set) in-app purchase for downloading all (three) files.

Comment: its better to download complete set